# Can tfs feedback be recieved via TFS Web Access w/o installing feedbackclient.exe?

Tags: user-feedback, tfs-web-access

ON TFS2012 is it possible to request feedback from customers that are utilizing the web client without them having to install feedbackclient.exe on their machines

Answer (score 3):

[Usersnap](http://usersnap.com) allows customers to add feedback without installing anything locally. It integrates into Microsoft Team Foundation Service (this means, every feedback from your customers is automatically created as ticket inside your TFS workflow).

Your customers even don't need an account in TFS to provide feedback.

It's easy to integrate Usersnap with TFS, you can have a look at the docs here: https://usersnap.com/support/docs/apicfg#tfs

Answer (score 0):

To work with the feedback request like it is explained [here](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/collaborate/feedback/) it is not possible to give feedback without installing the client tool.

I thought it would work also by logging in in the TFS web interface then open the feedback request and answer to it but apparently after testing it myself I did not found a solution directly. Though the feedback would be filled in completely manually while all the needed tools are available with the client tool.